# Blessings exiting bathroom

Tags: blessing, bathroom

After going to the bathroom *during* the day, does one recite al netalis yadiam and esher yatzarh?

Comment: On the other hand, the other question doesn't discuss Asher Yatzar. On the other hand, (how many hands do I have now), I don't think that Asher Yatzar is much of a question.

Comment: Most rishonim hold yes you say both.

Comment: Do you mean for the first time after waking up or later on in the day?

Comment: @sabbahillel The OP said ***during* the day**.

Answer (score 4):

The [Shulchan Aruch](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x350) writes in Orach Chai [(7:1)](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%96_%D7%90)

> כל היום כשעושה צרכיו, בין קטנים בין גדולים, מברך "אשר יצר" ולא "על נטילת ידים", אף אם רוצה ללמוד או להתפללא מיד
>
> If one uses the restroom throughout the day, whether for urination or defecation, one blesses "Asher Yatzar" but not "Al Netilas Yadaim", even if one wants to learn or pray right after.

The Taz says that the reason the blessing was instituted in the morning is because:

> דדווקא בשחר תקנו כן קודם התפילה, משום דרוב פעמים ידו נגע במקום מטונף, ולרשב"א משום דהוי כבריה חדשה.

1. It was insituted only in the morning, since people touch dirty things then or
2. The Rashba says that the blessing is for being a "new creation".

Comment: I assumed that נטילת ידים in the morning was specifically to remove the *Ruach Ra'ah* (I'm not sure exactly what this is) that occurs during sleep. Thus, the bracha doesn't apply the rest of the day.